# run php from another php without the caller waiting the called php to end

Tags: php

I would like one of my php files call another php file than proceeds to the next line without waiting the called php to end.

I can't use `exec` because it is disabled from my web server. ( see [phpInfo](https://000x.000webhostapp.com/phpInfo.php) if you like )

I can't use `include, require or get_file_contents` because they will make the caller php wait until the called one end (assume the called php has `sleep(60)` so the caller will stop execution for one minute)

so what shall I use?

Comment: Does the php script, you are trying to call, use `ignore_user_abort()` to set the [`ignore_user_about`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) setting?

Comment: No it doesn't. why?

Comment: The possible answers depend on the value of the `ignore_user_about` setting.

Comment: so what exactly do I have to do

Comment: Is the function `pfsockopen()` blocked or can it be used to send a HTTP request? And for that matter, what about the `fsockopen()` function and the cURL library? Actually, please [edit] your question to include the result of `phpinfo();` to your question.

Comment: 'pfsockopen()' is disabled and I have edited the question

Comment: You can use javascript method fetch()

Answer (score 0):

### I found these two solutions

using **file_get_contents**:

```
  //url of php to be called

$url = "example.php/test?id=1";

  //this will set the minimum time to wait before proceed to the next line to 1 second

$ctx = stream_context_create(['http'=> ['timeout' => 1]]);

file_get_contents($url,null,$ctx);

  //the php will read this after 1 second
```

using **cURL**:

```
  //url of php to be called

$url = "example.php/test?id=1";

$test = curl_init();

  //this will set the minimum time to wait before proceed to the next line to 100 milliseconds

curl_setopt_array($test,[CURLOPT_URL=>$url,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS=>100]);

curl_exec($test);

  //this line will be executed after 100 milliseconds

curl_close ($test);
```

in both case the called php must set `ignore_user_abort(true)`.